# openam - log write authorization failure

Tags: logging, openam

I am attempting to write to a log. As per the below:

```
java.util.logging.Logger logger = com.sun.identity.log.Logger.getLogger("name");
```

I then do:

```
public void info(SSOToken token, String message) {
    if (this.logger != null) {
        java.util.logging.LogRecord value = null;
        if (token == null) {
            value = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, message);
        }
        else {
            value = new LogRecord(Level.INFO, message, token);
        }

        logger.log(value);
    }
}
```

But am getting an exception:

```
com.sun.identity.log.AMLogException: MagentoIdRepo:Log write authorization failure
    at com.sun.identity.log.Logger.validateLogBy(Logger.java:291)
    at com.sun.identity.log.Logger.log(Logger.java:363)
    at com.sun.identity.log.Logger.log(Logger.java:340)
    at com.sun.identity.log.Logger.log(Logger.java:270)
```

Any idea how i'd find out what user needs to be authed to log and how i'd auth them? as i presume thats what i need to do to fix the above.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to do some debug logging you may use 'com.sun.identity.shared.debug.Debug' ...

```
private static Debug debug; 
debug = Debug.getInstance("someName");
if (debug.messageEnabled()) {
  debug.message(....);
}

if (debug.warningEnabled()) {
  debug.warning(...);
}
```

etc

If you really need the logger you started with special permissions have to be assinged to the identity which is related to the 'SSOToken'

Comment: Thanks. I think thats all i'll need.